# Detect angle of turn car took from Android

Tags: android, geolocation, logic, android-sensors, compass-geolocation

I want to implement a program which tells if car driver took a fast turn when my device is upright in holder.
I am getting speed from GPS and am currently using compass.
Whenever angle changes in same direction as previous it adds up the angle difference, but when it changes in opposite direction i set angle difference = 0 and so on.
It moves very swiftly in hand but in car it works 60 70% of times.
Due to error of sensors and style of driving.
Is there any other method like if i pass lat long and get back that its a turn or not..
Or am i implementing right or there's any better way to do it.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Bearing ?
Instead of using compass use the bearing that Location class offers:

```
loc.getBearing();
```

more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: No i haven't used that...  So i should get bearing from the last point it was stable to upto no change in bearing. As i did for the compass ?

Comment: yes, that makes sense. if you do the same you did with compass, since bearing is more "stable" that might solve your problem.

Comment: But bearing comes along with location, and you can not get location so quickly! It takes at least five seconds to get another location according to google's fused location api.